# unexpected behaviour of str_replace with array

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I've the following function and using `str_replace` gives an unexpected result

```
function repo($text) {
    $search = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    $replace = array("z30","z31","z32","z33","z34","z35","z36","z37","z38","z99");
    $text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
    return $text;
}

echo repo('0');
```

The expected answer is

```
z30
```

and instead I get

```
zz330
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function works this way.

0 changes to z30, php continues loop the arrays, then z30 contains '3', and 3 changes to z33.
Because of that returns 'z' + 'z33' + '0' = zz330.

Answer (score 2):

Just like [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) says:

> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a
>   previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
function repo($text){
    $search = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    $replace = array("z30","z31","z32","z33","z34","z35","z36","z37","z38","z99");
    $replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
    return strtr($text, $replacePairs);
}
```